how to properly reserve/lock a seat in a booking application
I am building a booking system for clients who want users to book rooms, food, travel, and events. Since there are a limited number of rooms and seats in any event, how do I handle the logic of holding a seat while the user makes the payment?
My tech stack is as follows:

Node.js (Backend)
Sequelize (ORM)
MySQL (Database)
React Native (Client side mobile app)
React.js (Admin console)

EDIT:
most of the online resources say that I should just create a state for holding that particular booking like "reserved". but how do I unreserve the seat once the time has elapsed?
@Andy mentioned that I should use cron-jobs but is cron-job the industry standard?

Usually I would go with a database record and state it accordingly.
If you have e.g. 3 states for the room "open"|"reserved"|"booked" you can switch to "reserved" during the payment. If the payment doesn't happen booking systems usually have something like "Your room is reserved for 10 minutes" or alike so the room changes to "open" again if the payment is not received and "booked" if the payment ocurred.
You can use a timeout or create a cron job to change to open again.

yes i understand this for room booking but then I have two questions: 1. is cron-job best option? what I mean to ask is what is the industry standard? 2. since events only has number of seats left shown, how do I handle reservation of seats over there?



The 'Industry standrd' depends on your use case. There is a huge difference if you are building a large scale system like eventim or a small scale system. There is no silver bullet here and you have to design around the expected load. A cron job is probably not enough as you have to take into account server outage, connection loss to your database.


If you have seats left shown you will need a variable which stores the seats and change that accordingly - then you can send that update with server sent events or websockets.



currently, it has around 10k total users and 5-6k monthly active users. a cron job might be highly inefficient for these many users. that is why I want a better solution that will take into consideration downtimes and scalability
